# Spring MVC + Spring Data JPA when the parent is updating, child was delete

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

When i run app in console, result is correct. Parent is updating, child not delete.

**app.java**

```
public class app {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.load("classpath:app-context-annotation.xml");
        ctx.refresh();

        ClientService clientService = ctx.getBean("jpaClientService", ClientService.class);
        UserService userService = ctx.getBean("jpaUserService", UserService.class);
        CustomerService customerService = ctx.getBean("jpaCustomerService", CustomerService.class);
        TroubleService troubleService = ctx.getBean("jpaTroubleService", TroubleService.class);
        Client newClient = clientService.findOne(8l);
        String newClientName = "IP 8";
        newClient.setClient(newClientName);
        clientService.saveClient(newClient);
        clientList("Find all:", clientService.findAll());
        System.out.println(client.getUserList());*/
    }
    private static void clientList (String message, List<Client> clientList) {
        System.out.println(message);
        for (Client client : clientList) {
            System.out.println(client);
        }
    }
    private static void userList (String message, List<User> userList) {
        System.out.println(message);
        for (User user : userList) {
            System.out.println(user);
        }
    }
    private static void troubleList (String message, List<Trouble> troubleList) {
        System.out.println(message);
        for (Trouble trouble : troubleList) {
            System.out.println(trouble);
        }
    }
}
```

But, when i using MVC, when the parent is updating all childs was delete from all tables.

**edit.jspx**

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
          xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
          xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
          xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_info" var="labelClientInfo"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_client" var="labelClient"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_id" var="labelId"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_inn" var="labelInn"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_specific" var="labelClientSpecific"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_address" var="labelClientAddress"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_phone" var="labelClientPhone"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_update" var="labelClientUpdate"/>
    <spring:message code="label_client_new" var="labelClientNew"/>
    <spring:eval expression="client.id == null ? labelClientNew:labelClientUpdate" var="formTitle"/>
    <html>
    <head><title>${formTitle}</title></head>
    <body>
    <h1>${formTitle}</h1>
    <div id="contactUpdate">
        <form:form modelAttribute="client" id="clientUpdateForm" method="post">
            <c:if test="${not empty message}">
                <div id="message" class="${message.type}">"${message.message}"</div>
            </c:if>
            <form:label path="client">
                ${labelClient}
            </form:label>
            <form:input path="client"/>
            <div>
                <form:errors path="client" cssClass="error"/>
            </div>
            <form:label path="inn">
                ${labelInn}
            </form:label>
            <form:input path="inn"/>
            <div>
                <form:errors path="inn" cssClass="error"/>
            </div>
            <form:label path="address">
                ${labelClientAddress}
            </form:label>
            <form:input path="address"/>
            <div>
                <form:errors path="address" cssClass="error"/>
            </div>
            <form:label path="phone">
                ${labelClientPhone}
            </form:label>
            <form:input path="phone"/>
            <div>
                <form:errors path="phone" cssClass="error"/>
            </div>
            <form:label path="clientSpecific">
                ${labelClientSpecific}
            </form:label>
            <form:select path="clientSpecific">
                <form:options items="${clientSpecific}"/>
            </form:select>
            <form:hidden path="version"/>
            <br/>
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
            <button type="reset">Reset</button>
        </form:form>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
</jsp:root>
```

**ClientController**

```
@RequestMapping("/clients")
@Controller

public class ClientController {
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ClientController.class);
    private ClientService clientService;
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list (Model uiModel) {
        log.info("Listing clients");
        List<Client> clients = clientService.findAll();
        uiModel.addAttribute("clients", clients);
        log.info("No. of Clients: " + clients.size());

        for (Client client : clients) {
            System.out.println(client);
        }
        return "clients/list";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String show(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model uiModel){
        Client client = clientService.findOne(id);
        uiModel.addAttribute("client", client);
        uiModel.addAttribute("users", client.getUserList());
        return "clients/show";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String update(Client client, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Locale locale){
        log.info("Updating client:");
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            uiModel.addAttribute("message", new Message("error", messageSource.getMessage("client_save_fail", new Object[]{}, locale)));
            uiModel.addAttribute("client", client);
            return "clients/update";
        }
        uiModel.asMap().clear();
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", new Message("success", messageSource.getMessage("client_save_success", new Object[]{}, locale)));
        clientService.saveClient(client);
        return "redirect:/clients/"+ UrlUtil.encodeUrlPathSegment(client.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String updateForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model uiModel){
        uiModel.addAttribute("client", clientService.findOne(id));
        return "clients/update";
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String create(Client client, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Locale locale){
        log.info("Creating Client:");
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            uiModel.addAttribute("message", new Message("error", messageSource.getMessage("client_create_fail", new Object[]{}, locale)));
            uiModel.addAttribute("client", client);
        }
        uiModel.asMap().clear();
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", new Message("success", messageSource.getMessage("client_create_success", new Object[]{}, locale)));
        clientService.saveClient(client);
        log.info("Client ID: " + client.getId() + "was created success");
        return "redirect:/clients/" + UrlUtil.encodeUrlPathSegment(client.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String createForm(Model uiModel){
        Client client = new Client();
        uiModel.addAttribute(client);
        return "clients/create";
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setClientService(@Qualifier("jpaClientService") ClientService clientService){
        this.clientService = clientService;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource){
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?
app-context == webapp-context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Deleted "orphanremoval=true" from entities.